# Integration code coverage with cobertura and ant

Tags: ant, sonarqube, cobertura

Anyone know if possible to separate the unit coverage and integration coverage on sonar using cobertura and ant? Can provide any example if it is possible?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible AFAIK. The best option for you is to use JaCoCo instead of Cobertura. You can use the following sample project to help you: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/it/ant/it-jacoco-ant